# How to match values in multiple list to create a tree

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
arr = [
    [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 1315L}], 
    [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3973L}], 
    [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3974L}], 
    [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3975L}], 
    [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3976L}], 
    [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3977L}], 
    [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3978L}], 
    [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3979L}], 
    [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3980L}], 
    [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3981L}], 
    [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3982L}], 
    [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3983L}], 
    [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3984L}], 
    [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3985L}], 
    [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 642L, 'article_id': 3986L}], 
    [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'option_id': 643L, 'article_id': 3987L}]
]
```

I want to create a tree which looks like this

```
tree = [
    15 [
        19 [
            642: {3974},
            643: {3975},
        ],
        20 [
            642: {1315},
            643: {3973},
        ],
    ],
    16 [
        19 [
            642: {3978},
            643: {3979},
        ],
        20 [
            642: {3976},
            643: {3977},
        ],
    ],
    17 [
        19 [
            642: {3982},
            643: {3983},
        ],
        20 [
            642: {3980},
            643: {3981},
        ],
    ],
    18 [
        19 [
            642: {3986},
            643: {3987},
        ],
        20 [
            642: {3984},
            643: {3985},
        ],
    ]
]
```

I don't know how to use Python's tools to achieve this. I doesn't need to be elegant but I just need to match all these lists to create a tree multi list.

Comment: I think @EdwinvanMierlo meant to say the `tree` (output) is not a valid syntax.  That makes the question unclear.

Comment: @wim ya, my bad... tree is not valid... (hand to forehead moment)... and lack of effort is also noted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of dictionaries using the following recursive function:

```
def add_path(idx, path, res_dict):
    node_dict = path[idx]
    key = node_dict['option_id']
    if 'article_id' in node_dict:
        res_dict[key] = node_dict['article_id']
    else:
        if key not in res_dict:
            res_dict[key] = dict()
        add_path(idx + 1, path, res_dict[key])


def option_tree(option_arr):
    result = dict()
    for path in option_arr:
        add_path(0, path, result)
    return result
```

---

When called with your example input, you get the following dictionary:

```
{
15: {
    20: {
            642: 1315,
            643: 3973
        },
    19: {
            642: 3974,
            643: 3975
        }
    },
16: {
    20: {
            642: 3976,
            643: 3977
        },
    19: {
            642: 3978,
            643: 3979
        }
    },
17: {
    20: {
            642: 3980,
            643: 3981
        },
    19: {
            642: 3982,
            643: 3983
        }
    },
18: {
    20: {
            642: 3984,
            643: 3985
        },
    19: {
            642: 3986,
            643: 3987
        }
    }
}
```

and can get a specific value as `result[15][20][643]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty easily build something similar to what you want as a nested dictionary:

```
tree = {}
for row in arr:
    d = tree
    for id_dict in row:
        if 'article_id' in id_dict:
            d.setdefault(id_dict['option_id'], []).append(id_dict['article_id'])
        else:
            d = d.setdefault(id_dict['option_id'], {})
```

If your `option_id` combinations are all unique, you might be able to get rid of the innermost list. Just replace the line `d.setdefault(id_dict['option_id'], []).append(id_dict['article_id'])` with the somewhat simpler `d[id_dict['option_id']] = id_dict['article_id']`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
import itertools

arr = [[{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 1315L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3973L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3974L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 15L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3975L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3976L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3977L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3978L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 16L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3979L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3980L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3981L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3982L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 17L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3983L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3984L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 20L}, {'article_id': 3985L, 'option_id': 643L}], [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3986L, 'option_id': 642L}], [{'option_id': 18L}, {'option_id': 19L}, {'article_id': 3987L, 'option_id': 643L}]]
def create_tree(d):
  s = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x:x[0]['option_id'])]
  return {int(a):{int(b[0][0]['article_id'])} if len(b) == 1 else create_tree([i[1:] for i in b]) for a, b in s}
```

Results:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(create_tree(arr))
```

Output:

```
{15: {19: {642: set([3974]), 643: set([3975])},
    20: {642: set([1315]), 643: set([3973])}},
 16: {19: {642: set([3978]), 643: set([3979])},
    20: {642: set([3976]), 643: set([3977])}},
 17: {19: {642: set([3982]), 643: set([3983])},
    20: {642: set([3980]), 643: set([3981])}},
 18: {19: {642: set([3986]), 643: set([3987])},
    20: {642: set([3984]), 643: set([3985])}}}
```

Comment: Because sorting degrades the time-complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: @wim Can you clarify? It looks correct, based on the OP's model.

Comment: Actually I don't know anymore. At a glance I had thought the OP tree was ordered, but it's invalid syntax. Answerers should probably wait until the question is edited.

Comment: Nonetheless my downvote stands, for writing a one-liner which needs to use the horizontal scroll to read.